# Multiple columns values comparison in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the dataframe with multiple rows, Based on a column I want compare each column values and find the column name.

for e.g
DF - id,name,address,street,city,country,zipcode
Based on ID, I want to find which fields have the discrepancy.

```
Seq(1,aaa,no55,melbourne,australia,00001)
Seq(1,aaa,no55,melbourne,australia,00002)
Seq(2,aaa,no55,melbourne,australia,00001)
Seq(2,aaa,no55,melbourne,australia,00001)
```

Here, zipcode have discrepancy in ID=1

How to do this with more efficient way, because I want check 50 columns in that dataframe. Thanks for advance.

Comment: Is there any set of rows to which could be compared your input data ? If yes so then it is possible somewhat

Comment: Yes FaigB, that is based on the ID column. Multiple same ID columns would be compare.

Answer (score -1):

Use `df.groupBy("all your columns here").count().filter("count  = 1").show` it will gave you all differed records at least with one column

Comment: Hi dude, I am using below query already and understood your above query.It will give the entire row But my perspective is need to get that exact column and corresponding value like Zipcode(00002)

DF.where(col("status").isin("YY", "XX")).groupBy("ref_no")
    .agg(countDistinct( "all my columns here").as("RULE1"))
    .where(col("RULE1").gt(1))